# Get handler from URI in Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Inside a `ContainerResponseFilter` I would like to get the "handler", i.e. the class where `@Path` and the `@GET`/`@PUT`-annotated method matches the URL I will provide.

Example:

```
someJerseyVariable.getHandlerForURI(request.getRequestUri());
```

I can't find any similar method.

The reason I want this, is to have statistics for how many requests each handler served and how many succeeded/failed. Any other alternatives are also welcome.

Comment: So how did you figure out how many succeeded/failed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can inject [`UriInfo`](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html) or [`ExtendedUriInfo`](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/ExtendedUriInfo.html). `UriInfo` contains only last matched class, `ExtendedUriInfo` can even report matched method (and much more info, see the linked javadocs).

Code sample:

```
public class Filter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    @Context UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Context ExtendedUriInfo extendedUriInfo;

    @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest request, ContainerResponse response) {
        System.out.println(uriInfo.getMatchedResources().get(0).getClass());
        System.out.println(extendedUriInfo.getMatchedMethod().toString());
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 And note that `ExtendedUriInfo` extends `UriInfo` so in practice there's no need to inject both.