# Jersey/Glassfish: what is consuming POST parameters?

Tags: glassfish, jersey-2.0

I have a Jersey 2.x servlet running under Glassfish 4.0.  There is a method that processes a form submission:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Path("/{serial}")
public Response saveUnit(....) { ... }
```

I get the message "A servlet request to the ... contains form parameters in the request body but the request        body has been consumed by the servlet or a servlet filter accessing the request parameters."

However, I don't have any filters defined.  Other than whatever Glassfish and Jersey do by default.

I do however have a listener defined (which I had forgotten about).

I suspect this is why my attempt to use MultivaluedMap isn't working.

Any ideas what is consuming the request?

Here is the Jersey method:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Path("/{unitid}")
public Response saveUnit(@PathParam("unitid")int unitId, @Context UriInfo uri) {
     MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = uri.getQueryParameters();

     for (String k:queryParams.keySet()) {
        logger.info(k);
     }

    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

The map queryParams is empty.

Here is my web.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mycompany.ApplicationConfig</servlet-name>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>mypackage</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mycompany.ApplicationConfig</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>mycompany.ServletContextClass</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I assume you have `MultivaluedMap` as one of the parameters and you want Jersey to bind the form entity into this map. Is the map empty? What are the other parameters of the method (if any)? Are they all injectable by Jersey? (Note: The message shouldn't be a problem, Jersey is still able to retrieve form params.)

Answer (score 1):

To get to the received form parameters in your resource method change the signature of the method to:

```
public Response saveUnit(@PathParam("unitid") int unitId,
                         final javax.ws.rs.core.Form form) {
    ...
}
```

or

```
public Response saveUnit(@PathParam("unitid") int unitId,
                         final MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData) {
    ...
}
```

Jersey will fill the values.

With your approach you're asking Jersey to return a map of query params (which are part of URI and assuming from the question you want `Form` params).

Comment: Sadly both approaches also result in empty data.

Comment: Ok, so let's what's registered. Do you have only Jersey servlet registered in your web.xml? No servlet filters? (see similar question for Jersey 1.x - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138876/how-to-get-form-parameters-in-request-filter)

Comment: I edited the question to include my web.xml.  Also, I had forgotten that I had a listener defined.

Comment: By any chance isn't that listener adding other servlet/filter that could consume the entity of a request? (btw: You should be still able to inject form parameters via `@FormParam`.)

Comment: I don't think so, the ServlerContextClass overrides contextInitialized() and reads a config file at startup.  It doesn't do anything else.

Comment: Are you using GF4.0 or some night build? (I need to find exact version of Jersey)

Comment: GF4.0, and I ran the update for jersey.  jersey-common.jar has Bnd-LastModified: 1368554878153 and Bundle-Version: 2.0.0, if that helps.

Comment: Thanks. If you remove the listener is there still a problem with Forms?

Comment: I removed the listener, it does not help.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to share your app with me? I need to debug it. If so, please write an email to Jersey users mailing list (see https://jersey.java.net/mailing.html) and I'll contact you directly.

Comment: Thanks.  Let me see if I can reproduce with a small test app.