# JSONFIlter and REST return Object instead of string

Tags: json, jersey, jackson

I am using JsonFilter to filter the properties. For this i needed to modify my REST api return type to String (json string) instead of Objects by following [How to return a partial JSON response using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314735/how-to-return-a-partial-json-response-using-java)

Question is how can i have REST api return my object types rather than string and still make use of JsonFilter.

```
// Filter object
@JsonFilter ("userFilter")
public class  User { }

// REST
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public UserWrapper getUsers(@QueryParam("fields") String fields) {
     UserWrapper  r = new UserWrapper  ();
     List<User>   users = x.getUsers(fields);
     r.setUsers(users)
     return r;
}
```

Question is i have how can i make the REST interface to return 'UserWrapper' instead Json String  ?  UserWrapper  does not have JsonFilter but include User which has JsonFilter.

thanks for you inputs.

vbp

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays there is no need to create an ObjectMapper inside a resource method and return a string to customize the JSON representation of the resulting object.

If you use [Jackson Views](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews) you can put `@JsonView` annotation directly on your resource method. See this JIRA for [more information](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-578).

Also you can customize the Jackson object writer inside the resource method using [the Jackson 2.3 ObjectWriterModifier/ObjectReaderModifier feature](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews). You can use this for overriding the current Jackson view ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23580762/3537858)) or configuring [the Jackson filters](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureJsonFilter) ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23816382/3537858)).