# JAX-RS: Retrieve path pattern in ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

I am implementing a pre matching `ContainerRequestFilter` and would like to retrieve the `@Path` pattern of my resource which is about to be invoked.

Here is my resource

```
Path("/v1/partner/{partnerId}/adresse")
public interface AdresseResource
{
   @GET
   @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
   public Response handleAdresseCollectionGet(@Context UriInfo uriInfo, @PathParam("partnerId") String partnerId);

   // Other methods omitted
}
```

In my filter I would like to get the `/v1/partner/{partnerId}/adresse` pattern from my Path annotation. But I can't get it out of the `ContainerRequestContext` instance. I would have expected this information within the `UriInfo` but `encodedPath` and `matchingPath` are the same.

Can you help me on this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the @PreMatching documentation](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/PreMatching.html):

> Global binding annotation that can be applied to a container request filter to indicate that such filter should be applied globally on all resources in the application before the actual resource matching occurs.

At the time your filter is invoked it's not clear which resource will be matched. Your Filter could change the requestUri or even the method which would affect the matching so you can't get this information here.

In a non `@PreMatching` ContainerRequestFilter you can get more information via [ContainerRequestContext.getUriInfo().getMatchedURIs()](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getMatchedURIs%28%29) or by injecting the [ResourceInfo](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceInfo.html) like already [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24823022/1353722).

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve this information using a post matching filter?

Comment: what is 'requestContext' here?

Comment: The single parameter of the single method in the mentioned ContainerRequestFilter.