# Swagger API documentation could not be read due to filters

Tags: rest, jax-rs, swagger

I am having the JAXRS application, where I want to expose the REST API via Swagger.

The configuration is the same as for the sample ([Swagger JAX RS sample](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/tree/master/samples/java-jaxrs)).

It had worked fine until I added several filters (javax.servlet.Filter and javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter) required for my application.

Filters work on /api/* path, and Swagger reads the documentation from /api/api-docs path.

Is it somehow possible to avoid filters for Swagger?

Comment: I believe [this][1] StackOverflow question answers your question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125296/can-i-exclude-some-concrete-urls-from-url-pattern-inside-filter-mapping

Comment: It solves javax.servlet.Filter problem, but how to skip javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter filters?

Comment: Possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043093/jax-rs-retrieve-path-pattern-in-containerrequestfilter

Comment: Already have URI. I would like to skip all filters when reading /api/api-docs path without modifying every filter and checking the URI.

Comment: I don't think there's a centralized solution for that. I believe it's filter-specific.

Comment: Please refer the following link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66740706/solution-swagger-api-of-spring-boot-restful-web-service-is-not-working-due-to

Comment: Please refer the following link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66740706/solution-swagger-api-of-spring-boot-restful-web-service-is-not-working-due-to

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. In web.xml I added the filter which handles the /api/api-docs/* request.
It is set before filters which handle /api/* requests.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SwaggerDocRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>my.package.filters.SwaggerDocRequestFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SwaggerDocRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/api-docs/*</url-pattern>     
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>   
</filter-mapping>
```

SwaggerDocRequestFilter looks like this:

```
    public class SwaggerDocRequestFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException {        
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String path = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
        if (path.contains("/api-docs")) {
            String forwardPath = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getServletPath() + 
                    StringUtils.defaultString(((HttpServletRequest)request).getPathInfo());

            request.getRequestDispatcher(forwardPath).
                    forward(request, response); 
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {} 
}
```

This overrides all `javax.servlet.Filter` implementations.

For overriding JAX RS filters, it is required to provide own implementation of `javax.ws.rs.container.DynamicFeature` interface. This implementation applies filters only when requests to specific resources occurrs, in my case for resources in a specific package.

```
    public class MyDynamicFiltersRegister implements DynamicFeature {

@Override
public void configure(final ResourceInfo resourceInfo, final FeatureContext context) {
        if (resourceInfo.getResourceClass().getPackage().getName().equals("my.package.resources))   {
             //register filters on FeatureContext objec only if resource in specific package.
             ...
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, Swagger UI works fine. 
On requests to specific resources, JAX RS filters are applied.