# Swagger API of spring boot RESTful web service is not working due to servlet filter

Tags: java, spring, swagger-ui

The servlet filter suppresses many swagger responses (including images and CSS) to create a **swagger-ul** GUI screen on the browser. Please bypass such acts by the following code snippet.

```
@Component
public class DomainAuthorizationFilter implements Filter {


    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        if(httpRequest.getRequestURI().trim().toLowerCase().matches(".*swagger-.*|.*api-docs.*"))
        {           request.getRequestDispatcher(httpRequest.getServletPath()).forward(request, response);
            return;
        }
        else {
              // Your login in the filter.
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We need to add the said filter and inside our spring-boot controller, we need to put like -

```
@ApiOperation(value = "description of method.", response = Object.class)
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "record found."),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "record not found") })
@ApiImplicitParams(value = {
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "header_1", value = "Provide header_1 in the header.", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "header"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "header_2", value = "Provide header_2 in the header.", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "header") })  
@GetMapping(value = "/getRecord", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseDTO<AccountDashboardDTO> getRecord()
{
    // Your business logic.
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Can you Provide the complete Solution