# Filters to intercept rest APIs

Tags: jersey

I want to write filter for reading annotation on resource class as well as methods for a Rest API. I am on Jersey 1.18.

I am trying to implement `ContainerRequestFilter`

I have registered `ResourceFilterFactory` in the web.xml as below. I was able to inject the abstract method, but wanted to know how do i read class level annotations.

```
<init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceFilters</param-name>
      <param-value>ariba.app.integrate.json.ScopeResourceFilterFactory</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to read the resource class annotations? Do you have some custom annotations?

Comment: Yes i do have some custom annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the answer in the below link, was very helpful.

[Reading annotations on methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673667/getting-resource-annotations-in-jersey-1-18-1-request-filter)

I read the annotation on a resource class as shown below.

```
method.getResource().getAnnotation(AnnotationName.class);
```