# Is there a way in Jersey to get the Class from URL

Tags: java, jersey

Say I have `@Path("/abc")` annotated on class `ABCResource`, does Jersey provide interface to retrospect which Class will be handling the coming uri, like this:
`public Class getHandlerClassForURL(URL url),` by invoking with 'abc' I would expecting `ABCResource.class` returned.

Is it possible in Jersey?

The reason why I need such utility is I have to provide a util to test if a specific menu-item(corresponding to @Path) is authorized to be visited before a real invocation occurs. So dynamic way won't help, such as `uriInfo.getMatchedResources()`, as I'm not intend to do this in a 'filter' or 'interceptor' circumstance.
I suppose inside Jersey, there should be a mapping like the `<servlet-mapping>` in web.xml, actually I do find one [here](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/linking/mapping/ResourceMappingContext.Mapping.html), sadly the key-value is opposite to my need.

Comment: I am not sure about Jersey but you can use plain Java reflection to match annotation values to your path value - provided you have a master list of classes to inspect to. Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402288/get-handler-from-uri-in-jersey) help?

Comment: The link you paste resembles my question, but the answer can not apply to my situation, since I want this method to be invoked 'static', i.e. not invoking when there is  a real request, thus depending on the injected request-related resource. And the reflection is a solution, if Jersey not provide such way, I might have to do like that.

Answer (score 0):

I would answer myself NO. According to 2 related questions, and the accepted answers show that they both have to workaround this instead of using a Jersey provided API directly at last. Links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484350/find-a-list-of-all-jersey-resource-methods-in-my-app) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303694/how-to-get-resource-method-matched-to-uri-before-jersey-invokes-it)